# In Lyx, is there a way to force global use of \cfrac instead of \frac?

Tags: lyx, fractions, displaystyle

I'm currently typing a document with a lot of equations with complex fractions. Is it possible to set the document to use `\cfrac` instead of `\frac` everywhere? I'm using Lyx's equation editor so it would be a pain to have to do it everywhere!

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does your document contain inline-math `\frac` expressions?

Comment: Thank you! No reason. \dfrac would work too. I just don't know how to change the fraction style globally for the whole document.

Comment: Have you tried globally changing `\frac` to `\dfrac`? That shouldn't be too painful to achieve, right?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you employ the `amsmath` package, you could run

```
\renewcommand\frac[2]{\dfrac{#1}{#2}}
```

in the preamble.

Note that any inline-math `\frac` expressions are likely to look awful as a result, unless you switch to `\tfrac` ("text-style frac").

Comment: @Sebastiano - Good eye! :-)

Comment: That's much better thank you. I have only very simple fractions inline and they look ok with dfrac. Cheers!